# How to rotate a Three.js Vector3 around another Vector3?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here I want to rotate 'endpoint' vector around 'startpoint' vector.

This rotates endpoint vector around world's z-axis:

```
 endpoint.copy(new THREE.Vector3(startpoint.x,startpoint.y,startpoint.z));
 endpoint.add(new THREE.Vector3(0, scale, 0 ));

 var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( axis_z, angle );
 endpoint.applyMatrix4( matrix );
```

I have tried to save vector's translation to temporary matrix, and after applying rotation, restore translation back to endpoint vector:

```
 endpoint.copy(new THREE.Vector3(startpoint.x,startpoint.y,startpoint.z));
 endpoint.add(new THREE.Vector3(0, scale, 0 ));  

 var translateMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(endpoint.x, endpoint.y,   endpoint.z);
 var translation = new THREE.Matrix4().copyPosition(translateMatrix); 
 translateMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis_z, angle);
 translateMatrix.copyPosition(translation);
 endpoint.applyMatrix4(translateMatrix);
```

This code works for rotations, but all the translations are wrong.
Is there an easy way for vector rotation relative to another vector?

UPD. Resolved this. I was blind. No need for translations. What I had to do: apply rotation to vectors delta (endpoint - startpoint), and in the end, add the rotated delta to startpoint (startpoint + delta):

```
var vector_delta = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(endpoint, startpoint);
vector_delta.applyAxisAngle( axis_z, rota );
endpoint.addVectors(startpoint, vector_delta);
```

Comment: It is not clear tp me what you are trying to do. Does `axis = startpoint.clone().normalize(); endpoint.applyAxisAngle( axis, angle );` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for response. It looks like I don't understand clearly 3D vectors math. What I was trying to do is just rotate one vector around other by any angle in any direction (any axis).  My first code gave me rotations around the center (0,0,0) of the world's axis, but not around startpoint vector.   Your code doesn't do what I want either, because it can rotate vector only around one axis, and there's no way to specify other axis rotation. Aghhh, I'm stuck.

Comment: So you want to rotate around the origin point and have any vector you want as the angle? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233319/have-object-revolve-around-vector-point/19234249#19234249) and see if that's closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Nope, I want to rotate around any arbitrary vector (non-zero). I've found a solution with the translation vector.