# Have object revolve around vector point

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am currently looking for a way to have an object orbit the vector coordinates 0,0,0.
For instance if the object is located at X300,Y50,Z200 than I would like it to revolve around 0,0,0 but I don't want to adjust the Y axis. I'm not great with math and this is proving to be very difficult to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well an orbit implies you have an axis. (0, 0, 0) is just a point in 3D space, so you'll need either another point ( -3, 8, 4 ) to then create a normalized axis from. If you use a Three.js `Object3D` you can simply normalize the `objects.up` property. But I digress, here's a simple vector example:

```
var startPoint = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
var axisVector = new THREE.Vector3( -3, 8, 4);
var endPoint = new THREE.Vector3( 300, 50, 200 );
var rotation = 0.05;

var axis = startPoint.clone().sub(axisVector).normalize();
endPoint.applyAxisAngle( axis, rotation );
```

Here's a fiddle using two cubes instead of bare `Vector3`'s [here](http://jsfiddle.net/csE7r/) Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. This allowed me to view the problem in a hole new light. I also found an alternate solution. I will share it below.

Comment: Glad to help, interestingly a `Vector3` has a length (sometimes called magnitude) which is essentially a pythagorean style magnitude based on the origin (0, 0, 0). This is why a `Vector3` at the origin has no usable magnitude for the purpose of a rotation axis.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following code allows an object to move in a circular pattern.

```
        function orbitRight() {
            var x = thisObj.position.x;
            var z = thisObj.position.z;
            thisObj.position.x = x * Math.cos(.02) - z * Math.sin(.02);
            thisObj.position.z = z * Math.cos(.02) + x * Math.sin(.02);
        }
```

Comment: Nice , can you suggest me how to simuate loot at  (opengles1.1) . I dont use three.js . I need rotation always in center like orbit controls in three.js ....