# Draw curved line in three.js from vector3 to vector3 on surface of SphereGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a sphere, and am receiving two vectors. I simply need to draw a line on the surface of my sphere to connect the points.

I feel like this problem is closely related to the Great-circle, but I'm not sure how I would go about implementing it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

I noticed that if xStart + xEnd is > 0, then xOffset is positive (same for y and z). This bends the curve to the shorted path around the globe. My issue is the curved line does not sit on the globe, and the height of the arc changes depending on the two points. I realize the offsets can't just be linear, but I'm not sure what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 100, 100);

//Skipping unrelated code and to include creating sphere mesh and adding it to the scene

var curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(
 new THREE.Vector3(xStart, yStart, zStart),
  new THREE.Vector3((xStart+xEnd)/2 + xOffset, (yStart+yEnd)/2 + yOffset, (zStart+zEnd)/2 + zOffset), //Midpoint with offset
 new THREE.Vector3(xEnd, yEnd, zEnd)
);

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints( 50 );

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, materialLine);
globe.scene.add(line);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope I don't re-invent a bicycle. The answer based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19234249/4045502)

Imagine that your two vectors and the sphere's center are vertices of a triangle.

When we have a triangle, we can find it's normal. That normal will be our axis and we'll simply rotate our first vector around it.

[image]

```
function setArc3D(pointStart, pointEnd, smoothness, color, clockWise) {
  // calculate a normal ( taken from Geometry().computeFaceNormals() )
  var cb = new THREE.Vector3(), ab = new THREE.Vector3(), normal = new THREE.Vector3();
  cb.subVectors(new THREE.Vector3(), pointEnd);
  ab.subVectors(pointStart, pointEnd);
  cb.cross(ab);
  normal.copy(cb).normalize();


  var angle = pointStart.angleTo(pointEnd); // get the angle between vectors
  if (clockWise) angle = angle - Math.PI * 2;  // if clockWise is true, then we'll go the longest path
  var angleDelta = angle / (smoothness - 1); // increment

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  for (var i = 0; i < smoothness; i++) {
    geometry.vertices.push(pointStart.clone().applyAxisAngle(normal, angleDelta * i))  // this is the key operation
  }

  var arc = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: color
  }));
  return arc;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/b7tfxg8r/) example.

Comment: Prompt, concise, code included, comments on code, picture included, interactive example, and I was able to understand and implement it in 5 mins... Even if you reinvented something you explained it like a boss

Comment: You're welcome ) It was interesting to find the solution of your question.